# List all products of publisher in play store

Tags: android

I want to get list of all apps of a particular publisher.
I have tried with https://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:"publisher name".
It gives result if I enter publisher name google, but if I enter my publisher name it does not gives me the list of my published apps.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: try proper name otherwise there may not be any app for the name you searching for..

Comment: @ahuja007 you can ref this:~ https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play.html and also get this way https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=XYZ+XYZ

Comment: I think you can try JSOUP  Library to get the publisher list for the play store.

Comment: @HarshitTrivedi  I tried with developer account which comes in URL while opening console. No luck in that.

I got the error : "We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server."

Comment: @HarshitTrivedi  I think I got that. After creating developer page, that link took me to my developer page. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @ahuja007 if you can find with your all app you get the result of your 
 app list https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Aexyn but you try https://play.google.com/store/search?q=Aexyn this get all related result of app

Comment: @ahuja007 I think no need to developer page you can put https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Aexyn this query you get all app and if you help full then plz up vote

Comment: @HarshitTrivedi Yeah that worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: @ahuja007 welcome and upvote the comment useful to post

Answer (score 2):

From an Android app: market://search?q=pub:publisher_name

From a web site: http://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:publisher_name

publisher_name SHOULD BE SAME AS ORIGINAL NAME INCLUDING SPACING AND OTHERS.

Comment: Yes I have tried the same. My publisher name is "Aexyn".
and I get result - https://pasteboard.co/GJ4haGY.png

Comment: And when I simply search Aexyn I get other apps too 
https://pasteboard.co/GJ4hvP8.png

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking list of search results for google play store, here is the code to list all the apps of a publisher. Happy Coding!

```
https://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:< PUBLISHER NAME>&c=apps
```

Example:

```
https://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:Google LLC&c=apps
```