# How to see all apps by a given publisher in the Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, publish, publisher

How to see a list of all apps published by a specific publisher in the Google Play Store?

There are related questions like [List all products of publisher in play store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46067237/list-all-products-of-publisher-in-play-store) on-site, but they don't provide the appropriate answer.

I tried either:

- [https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=[ID]](https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=%5BID%5D)
- [https://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:[NAME]&c=apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:%5BNAME%5D&c=apps)

The first yields max. 150 apps of any given publisher, the latter only max. 100. How may I access the full list?
According to Google's own documentation, there aren't any limits / quotas as far as these searches are concerned. But considering the both results differ, there are obviously differentiating approaches.

**Edit**: As requested per an user in the comments, here is a concrete example. "Rollic Games" is one of those publishers which has more than 150 apps.

If viewed in the "id view" (first option mentioned above) it displays EXACTLY 150 Apps:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=6018074114375198913

You can also search for them in the "search view" (second option), here it displays 100 apps!
https://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub%3ARollic%20Games&c=apps

So all in all: **How can I see a list of ALL apps published by any given publisher?**

Comment: Note: I'm sure that the publisher accounts have more than 100 apps published. But apparently the two different views have a limitation to how many you can inspect. According to the documentations and official sources, it shouldn't exist any limits. Therefore is the question how I may fetch ALL apps?

Comment: Could you name a concrete publisher? I have a vague idea but I don't know a publisher with enough apps for your use case, therefore I lack testing material. And I don't want to trash SO with an unripe idea.

Comment: @Krokomot Sure! Shoot your idea - I can re-offer the bounty as well ;) An example publisher is "Rollic Games". If viewed in the "id view" (first option): https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=6018074114375198913 it displays EXACTLY 150 Apps. You can also search for him in the "search view" (second option): https://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub%3ARollic%20Games&c=apps here it displays the exact 100 apps!

Comment: I think that's one of the best examples.. But there are hundreds of developer with these many apps published. There is no limit to how many apps can be published and those publisher have more apps online - but somehow it only displays those few limited. I thought of an enumerating work-around (e.g. searching for the developer + "a", "b", etc. to find all apps, but this shouldn't be the working solution).... I just want to find all their apps.

Comment: Put down some ideas on paper, so to say. Trying to dig deeper. If not -- may they inspire somebody.

Comment: I don't mean to be a stickler, but how is this programming-related?

Answer (score 1):

**Warning**: This is an answer in progress. If at all. Maybe it's an overlarge comment. I have no clue. But I hope to extend it with time. If not, it may provide information for other truth seekers. *Indiana Jones -- Raiders of the Lost Apps*.

Thanks to [J.M.Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14852784/j-m-arnold) for his supportive efforts!

---

#### Preface

The official documentation is the site [Linking to Google Play](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play) on the Android Dev Docs. Neither there nor anywhere else one finds a restriction on the number of apps to be shown.

#### Idea 1: Applying Google Search semantics

Can one apply the parameters for Google's search engine like `num` on Google's play store?

*Result*: Negative. Tried it. Correct me, if I'm wrong.

#### Idea 2: Who can what we can't?

Does *any* site or store display *all* play store apps of Rollic Games (our animal de laboratoire)?

*Result*:

- [mobileaction.co](https://www.mobileaction.co/publisher/android/rollic-games/Rollic%20Games/us): Nope, shows also exactly 150 apps
- [apkpure.net](https://apkpure.net/developer/Rollic%20Games?page=1), a kind of play store mirror, shows us *all* 156 apps on 8 pages. Access pattern (PHP-alike pseudocode):

```
$i = 1;
$HTMLcode = 0;
while($HTMLcode != 404) // one gets the general idea, I suppose, for precision see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status
{
    $HTMLcode = access("https://apkpure.net/developer/Rollic%20Games?page=".$i);
    $i++;
}
```

- Several other sites show even *less* than 150 apps.

So, let's stop here. How does apkpure.net know about >150 apps, when the play store itself shows maximum 150? Where's the crystal skull? (No, the play store seems to ignore a "page" parameter or similar stuff, so that's not the point).

Well, [J.M.Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14852784/j-m-arnold) played around with the apps on APKPure and noticed that about 5%-10% percent of the apps listed by big publishers aren't on the Android Store. He suggests that they may have scraped them over time, i.e. they are not searching for specific publishers and may have just added new apps over time to their repository. By constant scraping one could explain this phenomena.

#### Idea 3: Scrape it!

Some open-source play store scraper like [google-play-scraper](https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper/blob/main/README.md). Does that show everything? And if yes, how? What secrets are hidden in those ancient javascript runes?

Some time later... So. Installed `google-play-scraper` via `npm` and wrote three self-explaining scripts (for docs see link above) which should output up to 200 hits:

Search apps via developer by numeric ID:

```
var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');
gplay.developer({devId: "6018074114375198913", num: 200}).then(console.log);
```

Search apps via developer by name:

```
var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');
gplay.developer({devId: "Rollic Games", num: 200}).then(console.log);
```

Search by developer resp. publisher via, well, `search()` function by name:

```
var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');
gplay.search({term: "pub:Rollic Games", num: 200}).then(console.log);
```

Execute per shell e.g. by Bash with

```
$ node script.js > result.txt
```

Check results e.g. with `cat result.txt` for correctness and count the apps:

```
$ cat test.txt | grep "title: " | wc -l
```

*Result*: Negative. All three scripts find exactly the same apps. And exactly 100, though the `num` value for the `search()` function allows up to 250:

> `num` (optional, defaults to 20, max is 250): the amount of apps to retrieve.

Great. Not even 150 hits for a search by numerical dev ID.

(*Edit: [J.M.Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14852784/j-m-arnold) got 150 with the first approach, which would be actually the expected result. Strange.*)

Cringe... I'll take a look into the scraper's source code to find something useful.

*Later...* Looking into the scraper's source hasn't brought much. Interestingly it seems to apply the `num` parameter known from Google Search. However, as we already know by manual tests as well as using the scraper, it is ignored. However that might indicate, that it maybe was supported in the past. Or not, who knows.

#### Intermediate Conclusion

Kind of dead-end for now. We need somehow more info.

*Note: See the last comments below for the most recent developments. However, there's no breakthrough so far.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Interestingly enough, I checked with some publishers with apkpure.com and they showed 600+ apps for a big publisher... So somehow apkpure is able to fetch more than displayed! I've played around with parameters on the Play Store page as well - but wasn't able to reverse engineer / find anything relevant. Maybe apkpure constantly scans for new apps and logs those (i.e. has an archive of some sort?) or maybe they have access to an API?

Comment: Anyhow, apkpure is a very good lead to start with! Somehow we need to find out how they fetch all apps from a given publisher!

Comment: What's also weird is that for another publisher they (apkpure) listed LESS apps than on the official Google Play Store!

Comment: Maybe some kind of refresh latency. That would also explain the lesser app counts on other sites.

Comment: You know what -- Feel free to edit my post anytime you find something worth to mention.

Comment: Updated. You will be "enthusiastic" ^^

Comment: Thanks for the add-on! I tested the library as well and couldn't reproduce your results. With all three variants I didn't get over 150. The first approach yielded 150 elements and the other two just the 100 (similar to the interface ID <-> name in my description)! Were you able to fetch more than 150 with any of these code snippets?

Comment: No, you misread my irony ;-) I got the same result as you, with the strange difference that I fetched exactly 100 in **all** three cases, though your result is more logic and would be the expected one. Correct my post if necessary. My only hope is that I can find some kind of limit in the source code. But that approach didn't yield any results for now..

Comment: Ahh, gotcha! :D Very odd behavior of the Google Play Store, especially considering that there is no documented case regarding this.. Someone must have tried to do the same in the last couple of years? I haven't found any cross-reference or other article mentioning the issue. Furthermore, how is an external third-party able to offer such a vast amount of apps.. Very odd! ^^

Comment: Take a look at the precise names of Rollic Games apps, e.g. **com.crescivegames**.twistedtangle, **com.adengames**.weaponcraftrun, etc. They seem to be distributors and/or ordering party (for fast'n'cheap apps) rather developers themselves. Each app will probably earn not much, but the income is scaled up by a sheer mass of apps.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that as well! That's why I wanted to check for all their apps - do some research.

Comment: BTW -- that means that apkpure.com can't use an approach along the apps' names as there is no uniform pattern like com.rollicgames.xxx

Comment: I've played around with the apps on APKPure and noticed that about 5%-10%ish percent of the apps listed by big publishers aren't on the Android Store.. Leaving me to believe that they may have scraped them over time? I.e. they are not searching for specific publishers and may have just added new apps over time to their repository! By constantly scraping we could explain this phenomena. Still very odd that their is no *official* reasoning for the limits. @Krokomot

Comment: Sounds plausible, regarding Apkpure. Currently I got the feeling we reached some dead-end if we don't get **any** further info somewhere. Wherever that might be...

Comment: Looking into the scraper's source hasn't brought anything. Interestingly it seems to apply the *num* parameter known from Google Search. However, as we already know by manual tests as well as using the scraper, it is ignored. However that might indicate, that it maybe was supported in the past. Or not, who knows -.-

Comment: Updated with our last "insights".

Comment: I don't think it was possible ever.. I've seen a few issues on the GitHub, e.g. [#625](https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper/issues/625), [#450](https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper/issues/450), [#448](https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper/issues/448), [#451](https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper/issues/451) and many more. Those issues don't specifically align with our task, but apparently there are other methods/functions with a `num` parameter which doesn't work.

Comment: Most of those are from 2020 onwards. Only interesting thing I found was a comment on an issue (can be seen [here](https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper/issues/333#issuecomment-529290209)). This links to PR [#337](https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper/pull/337) which talks about an update that occurred on 2019-09-01 (from Google Play Store side). Apparently, there are similar issues... Maybe this is a point to follow through?

Comment: Digging through the issues and PRs in the repo right now.. Maybe we'll be able to find a work-around. They are talking about general searches (not necessarily with `dev:`).. :)

Comment: We don't even get those 200 hits. The last issue claiming 200 hits is from March 2023 from a seemingly Chinese user. We're both in Germany. Could there be some Geo-issue? (Sounds strange, I know, but well...)

Comment: Maybe trying with a VPN? Very odd! @Krokomot

Comment: btw, I gave the question once again a bounty.

Comment: Hope never dies ^^

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can find an app published by that specific publisher or else I think you can search the publisher name in the Play Store search bar and find all the applications that person has published. But you have to see if the publisher's name is the same as the name you searched.

Comment: That's a *very* general answer. You might want to read the OP's question again.